# Difference in assigning variable within bash vs command line

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I've always been assigning the results of a command to a variable, in bash, using back ticks but over the last 24 hrs or so, I've seen a mismatch in what I expect. I'm running this on Ubuntu 18 and within a script, attempting to get the major.minor version of PHP installed on a system. Using the command line, under a bash shell, I can write the following:

```
php -v | head -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F"-" '{print $1}' | awk -F"." '{print $1"."$2}'
```

and I get (for example) `7.2` displayed on screen, showing that I have PHP7.2 installed on this system. However, when I pop this into a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
phpVer=`php -v | head -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F"-" '{print $1}' | awk -F"." '{print $1"."$2}'`
echo ${phpVer}
```

... I get `PHP7.` printed out, and not the expected `7.2` that I saw when I ran on the command line??

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: Double check the commands are the same: when I tested your code I got the same output ("7.3") using either method. Also, good idea to switch from backticks to $() i.e. `phpVer=$(php -v | head -n1 | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F"-" '{print $1}' | awk -F"." '{print $1"."$2}')`

Comment: If you compare `php -v | head -1 | cut -c5-7` and `phpVer=$(php -v | head -1 | cut -c5-7)` does the output differ?

Comment: I also get no difference, And I checked it now with all versions from 5.6 to 7.3

Comment: This is besides the point, but you can do this with just a single call to sed `phpVer=$(php -v | sed -n 's/PHP \([[:digit:]]\+\.[[:digit:]]\+\).*$/\1/p')`

Comment: So is this solved (use cut instead of 3 awks), or do you still have a problem?

Comment: All - many thanks for the pointers and comments. Although I've yet to nail down exactly what was going on, I think it ended up being a display issue - the code was part of a larger script and once I pull just this piece out and run it (with both backticks and the more appropriate $() format) I do get the response I was expecting. Many thanks for confirming that I wasn't going (that) mad

Comment: I'm SUCH an idiot ... I had a function named "php" ... The Complete Donut Cup foolishly awarded to me ...